# How to get the bearer token from a webhook Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks, bearer-token

I receive datas from webhook and I try to get the `Authorization Bearer token` that is in the headers

I tried :

```
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts "TOKEN " + data['csrf-token']['content']
```

Also :

```
if headers['Authorization'].present?
  puts " HEADER " + headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
 else
   puts "ERROR"
end
```

-> I have the ERROR

And :

```
data = response.body
puts "TOKEN " + data['csrf-token']['content']
```

-> It returns nil

Turns out that the solution was :

```
bearer_token = request.headers["Authorization"]
```

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```rb
data = JSON.parse(response.body)
#⇒ JSON::ParserError (767: unexpected token ...
```

The library you use to get the response seems to parse the response on its own, you don’t need to call `JSON#parse` again. The below should work.

```rb
data = response.body
puts "TOKEN " + data['csrf-token']['content']
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

.....

I think you can get **Authorization Bearer token** like :-

```
if headers['Authorization'].present?
  return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
else
  errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
end
```